# Function to show result in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ecmascript-5

I need to make this script to print the result (true, or false) for the transparency of the image in the divs according to the area if its transparent or not.

Here is the example where I can see the result if its transparent but only on mouse move and for pixel by pixel according to the pointer.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdichev/0jhazjoa/

Here i have put a overlay over the image with 1/10 of the size square divs which I would like to change colors depending if they have transparent pixels in their area or not

https://jsfiddle.net/kdichev/ae9pjstm/1/

Ideally if there is one pixel below the box it should have a red background color or print in it false.

```
(function () {
var img = new Image(),
    output = document.getElementById('transparent'),
    bImg = document.getElementById('img');
img.src = bImg.src;

function isTransparent(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('imgcheck-canvas') || (function (_this) {
        var e = document.createElement('canvas');
        e.setAttribute('width', _this.width);
        e.setAttribute('height', _this.height);
        e.setAttribute('id', _this.id + '-canvas');
        e.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        var cx = e.getContext('2d');
        cx.drawImage(_this, 0, 0, _this.width, _this.height);
        return e;
    })(this);
    if (canvas.getContext === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    output.innerHTML = ((ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3] === 0) ? true : false);
}

function init() {
    console.log('init');
    bImg.addEventListener('mousemove', isTransparent, false);
}

img.addEventListener('load', init, true);


})();
```

Comment: The fiddle links are broken.

Comment: Hello thanks for the attention but this is an old question on which I have found solution. Don't know why fiddles are broken